# UWP NavigationView and TabView collision

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app

As you can see from the top of the image, the hamburger button of the `NavigationView` overlaps with my `TabView.TabStartHeader`. The `TabView` is in a `Frame` of `MainPage` while  `NavigationView` is in the `MainPage`.

Now I want them aligned horizontally with the hamburger button on the left and the Add button on the right. How can I achieve that?

[image]

XAML of MainPage: https://github.com/SeakyLuo/SMPlayer/blob/master/SMPlayer/MainPage.xaml

XAML of TabView: 
https://github.com/SeakyLuo/SMPlayer/blob/master/SMPlayer/PlaylistsPage.xaml

Comment: Can you add the XAML code so that it is easier for others to understand and answer your question ?

Comment: @Pratyay I really want to. But I am not sure how much code I need to post because it's related to 2 pages of xaml. I thought posting an image should have shown enough information. Per your request, I have added the links to them.

Comment: You can add the code for the `MainPage`.. that should be enough since it has the `Frame` and the `NavigationView`

Comment: @Pratyay I have posted the link to the `MainPage`. The structure is of `NavigationView` is very simple and I didn't change the Hamburger Button of that. `MainPage` would not be very informative IMO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem that you are facing is due to the default behavior of the `NavigationView`. Whenever the window size is reduced to a certain limit, `PaneDisplayMode` is changed to `LeftMinimal` to increase the viewable area . Thus the `Frame` which was previously sitting beside the navigation view is now directly below the navigation bar . Due to this, the "New Tab" button of the `Tab View` goes below the "hamburger Button" of the navigation bar .

The highlighted selection shows the area covered by the Frame which has the page with the TabView

### [image]

To prevent this from happening the easiest way would be to specify a single `PaneDisplayMode` for all screen sizes :

```
<NavigationView
            x:Name="MainNavigationView"
            ........
            PaneDisplayMode="LeftCompact">
```

---

A *better* approach would be to switch the `PaneDisplayMode` using `VisualStateManager` or Adaptive Triggers .

For example you can have the `PaneDisplayMode` as 'Auto' for window size greater than ~700px (based on your preference) and for lower window sizes you can switch it to 'Top'/'Left Compact'.

**XAML Code**

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="VisualStateGroup">
            <VisualState x:Name="VisualStateMin0">
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="MainNavigationView.(NavigationView.PaneDisplayMode)" Value="LeftCompact"/>
                </VisualState.Setters>
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="1" MinWindowHeight="1"/>
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="VisualStateMin700">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="700" MinWindowHeight="1"/>
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

You should see a behavior like this :

`PaneDisplayMode` - **Top** for small window size :

[image]

`PaneDisplayMode` - **Left Compact** for small window size :

[image]

---

**Update after [Seaky Luo's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11979678/seaky-luo) comment :**

Exact solution (though it does not look as *natural* as the other solutions):

For this you will need to add left margin to the "New Tab" button when the window size is small and the `NavigationView` switches to `LeftMinimal`.

I found that when the width is around ~640 the navigation view goes into `LeftMinimal` (you might have to fine tune that number).

**XAML Code :** [To be added to the Page called within the frame (PlayListsPage.xaml in this case)]

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="VisualStateGroup">
            <VisualState x:Name="VisualStateMin0">
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="NewPlaylistButton.(FrameworkElement.Margin)">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <Thickness>40,0,0,0</Thickness>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </VisualState.Setters>
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="1" MinWindowHeight="1"/>
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="VisualStateMin640">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="640" MinWindowHeight="1"/>
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

It should look something like this :

[image]

Hope this helps !

Comment: What if I still want the `LeftMinimal` but with the Hamburger Button on the left of  New Tab Button?

Comment: I cloned your project to dig deeper into it .. and, yes you can do that too.. I will update my answer shortly .. though it might not look as *natural* as the other solutions ..

Comment: Thank you so much! It's super helpful!

Comment: For those who only want to disable the minimal mode, `LeftMinimal`, set `<NavigationView CompactModeThresholdWidth="0">`